# Extract data element from Mongo DB using PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the following structure in a mongo collection:

[image]

By applying this chunk of code, I am able to extract the _id, priority, createdAt and updatedAt.

```
for i in col_keys.find({"updatedAt": {"$gte": startDate, "$lt": endDate}}):
    Id = i["_id"]
    priority = i["priority"]
    createdAt = i["createdAt"]
    updatedAt = i["updatedAt"]
    nameElement = i["name"]
    for j in nameElement.keys():
        value = nameElement[j]["value"]
```

But when I try to access the name object (using the nested for loop) to get also the value and source inside of that structure, I´m getting the following error:

[image]

It seems like I can´t access to the name element using the second for loop, what could I add to that loop to extract the elements inside the name element?

Comment: If you want `name.value` you can just do `i['name']['value]`. Iterating over the `keys()` is going to populate `j` with `"value"` meaning that the first iteration `nameElement[j]` _is_ the value you're looking for. Which makes the expression `nameElement[j]["value"]` the same as `"some string"["value"]` which is not valid in python.

Comment: Great thanks Henry!! it worked