# Extract element from Mongo DB using PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the following structure in a mongo collection:

[image: mongo DB structure]

This is the same question like in [Extract data element from Mongo DB using PyMongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761524/extract-data-element-from-mongo-db-using-pymongo)

I just could iterate over the name and the assetClass elements then extract the name.value and assetClass.value to a pandas dataframe, but when I try to do the same with any other of the elements and try to extract for example the value inside cusip, that´s when I am getting another error, for me difficult to explain because if I could access the name.value and assetClass.value, why couldn't I access to another element.value inside that structure?

The following is the for loop I am using, and works before to extract name.value and assetClass.value, but adding any other element.value, it errors

```
for i in col_keys.find({"updatedAt": {"$gte": startDate, "$lt": endDate}}):
    Id = i["_id"]
    priority = i["priority"]
    createdAt = i["createdAt"]
    updatedAt = i["updatedAt"]
    name = i["name"]["value"]
    asset = i["assetClass"]["value"]
    cusip = i["cusip"]["value"]
```

[image: error log]

Comment: Can `cusip` ever be null/undefined/empty?

Comment: Hi Henry, and thanks for your help again, yes it is possible that I have null/undefined/empty inside the cusip.value.

Comment: Hmmm. Now on second though you'd get a different error if that was the issue... Can you `print(i)` (edit to remove any sensitive data as needed) and put that dictionary in your question? It's a little hard to determine document structure from the image alone.

Comment: Yes, what I did at last was append the whole dictionary inside the ´i´ extracted into a list and then to a csv to be manipulated afterwards in a google sheet. Unfortunatelly, I can´t show here images of the real data inside the mongo structure because is private data from an enterprise application, but thanks for your help anyway Henry!!